# Rails associate record counting inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models, story & vote. I have a list of articles which a user can up vote which is stored as a separate vote in the vote model.

The story model has many votes and the story_id is stored with the vote record.

At the moment in my index action on the story view I'm just trying to do a simple count to see how many votes a given story has, I'm achieving this with the following code.

```
<%= @total_votes = Vote.where(:story_id => story.id).count %>
```

However I'd like to remove this from my story index action view but not sure were to store it? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the relationship is story has many votes. So, you can simply do:

```
<%= story.votes.count %>
```

If you are worried about database performance you may want to add a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).

Comment: Just seen this one, very simple. Will this be better on the database?

Comment: No, if you are worried about that you have to use a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column). In terms of efficiency it's exactly the same as the other answer. I just think making an extra instance method is nonsense.

Comment: @Mischa, you're right, that's why I deleted my answer: no need to let it since I think yours is the good one: +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, @siekfried. +1 for your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the model you could define a method and use it in the controller.

```
def total_votes(sid)
  where(:story_id => sid ).count
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
@total_votes = Vote.total_votes(story_id)
```

Comment: @Mischa: You may be right when you make an assumption that both models have a relationship. But the question did not mention that anywhere - not even a hint, so I thought a generic approach was more appropriate.

Comment: There is a small hint that vote belongs to story, namely the fact that the votes table has a `story_id` column. If the relationship had not been established in the models, the correct answer IMO would be to suggest creating that relationship instead of the "workaround" that you're suggesting. (Which, by the way, is incorrect now that I look at it again. It should be: `def self.total_votes(sid)`.)

Comment: Thats correct. Agree. And thanks for pointing out => def self.total_votes(sid)

Answer (score 0):

You said you'd like to store the total votes value:

```
$~ rails g migration add_total_votes_to_stories total_votes:integer

class Story
  after_save, :update_total_votes

  private

  def update_total_votes
    write_attribute :total_votes, votes.count
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

this should go in controller

```
def index
  @total_votes = Vote.where(:story_id => story.id).count
end
```